# Separating network data by using attribute table field

Tags: arcmap, field-calculator, attribute-table, network, symmetric-difference

I'm trying to separate historic network data (by symbology) that I need in the same shapefile, as my data contains two different types of network "Route" and "Stairs".

I tried using the classic that is adding a field to the attribute table which actually separates the polylines by their type accordingly. But the problem resides in the fact that the data I'm about to vectorize is unbelievably big.

So what I'm really in need of here is a way to group edit the many polylines and separate them in a field with either "Route" or "Stairs", in hopes there is a way around changing the type of network one by one which would take some undesirable amount of time.

[image]

Comment: What is your question?  If there was a single question mark somewhere in your question body that would be obvious.

Comment: @PolyGeo Did you actually read the post? I clearly mentioned what I needed, which is a way to group edit the Type field into the according one of two network types "?"

Comment: I never comment on a question that I have not read.  Your question body appears to contain at least two statements that *could* be interpreted as questions but neither is marked as one to tell us the single question that you wish to ask.  Network Analyst questions are amongst the most time consuming that I volunteer time to help with here and I do not commence them until I am certain about what is being asked.

Comment: @PolyGeo Is it any clearer now?

Comment: No - now it ends with "so what I'm really in need of here is a w" and appears to be truncated,  There is still no question mark present.

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm sorry truncated how?? I'll rephrase this simpler and clearer. Is there a way for me to vectorize a road network (in one single shapefile) separately by symbol for each of the two types of segment/polylines that this network data consists of ("Route", "Escalier").

Comment: It’s no longer truncated. I’m guessing your and my last comments were during the 5 minute edit window, and that you abandoned an edit.

Comment: @PolyGeo No idea. Now it's clearer, do you have any idea how I can work this out??

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm not able to volunteer more time to get this into the shape needed before I would be willing to develop an answer.  Hopefully, another potential answerer will be willing to work with you on this.

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to group edit features?  Select all the route features and set to "Route" then all the stair features and set to "Stairs".  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Midavalo Pretty much yeah but in the attribute table as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: @Midavalo matter of fact or in any possible way that would allow me to have two separate symbols for each network type, but still has to be in one same shapefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit attributes of multiple selected fields from the attribute table by using the Field Calculator.

1. Select all the features you would like to edit (eg all the `Route` features)
2. Right-click on the column header (Named `Type` in your screenshot) and click on "Calculate Field"
3. In the Field Calculator window enter the value you would like to populate onto the selected features, eg `ROUTE`
4. Click OK to calculate the value onto your selected features.
5. Clear the selection and now select all your `Stair` features and repeat the process.